# Siunitx bold units in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx, bold

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[reset-math-version = false]{siunitx}
    
\begin{document}

\tikz \node[draw=red, ultra thick, font=\bfseries, text width=4cm, text centered] (a) {Some 
text\\ size is $\qty{5}{\milli\meter} \times \qty{5}{\milli\meter}$};

\end{document}
```

How to make `qty` print number and unit in bold as surrounding text? I also tried `{\boldmath $...$}`, doesn't work.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

With suggestion from Joseph Wright's answer I get:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[text-series-to-math]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    
\tikz \node[draw=red, ultra thick, font=\bfseries, text width=4cm, text 
centered] (a) {Some text\\ size is $\qty{5}{\milli\meter} \times \qty{5} 
{\milli\meter}$\\ 5\,mm and $\mathbf{5}\,\text{mm}$};
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can only get all in bold by hand, as in the last row. Probably I don't understand the suggestion of `text-series-to-math`.

Comment: Your font choice here means the `5` doesn't look all that bold even though it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You are sending bold from text to math mode: you want `text-series-to-math`. In contrast, `reset-math-version = false` is about 'carrying forward' for example sansmath.

---

Your edit suggests you want `siunitx` to print in text mode. For that, you set `mode = text`, then also apply `reset-text-series = false` so the series (bold, *etc.*) carries through.

---

In general, `siunitx` starts off using math mode, and unless you request it doesn't print in text mode. When you request text mode printing, it does it's best to make sure all symbols are 'safe', so for example replacing `\times` by `\texttimes`.

Comment: I edited question with your suggested option, still doesn't work for me :(.

Comment: @Alx You are getting bold math mode, but it sounds like you actually want to print in text mode: I've edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: yes now it works, thanks! But could you elaborate a bit about the difference between math and text modes in siunitx, for newbie like me. I'm honestly confused what I need: I thought, if I have `times` sign it should be printed via math mode. When one should use one or the other mode, and why there is so difficult to get bold in math mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}    % I haven't this font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\tikz   \sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text} 
        \node[draw=red, ultra thick, font=\bfseries, text width=4cm, align=center] (a) 
                {Some text\\ size is \qtyproduct{5x10}{\milli\metre}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I'm still not familiar with `siunitx` syntax introduced by version 3.0, so there may be more appropriate option as are used in above MWE.